How would I go about deleting data in a dataframe?
I'm looking for duplicated reservation ID's and then attempting to delete them from the spreadsheet. This is not working as it should. Where did I go wrong?
I tried using
dataRange = file1[~file1['Reservation ID'].isin(file2['Reservation ID'])]

file1 = file1.drop(file1.index[dataRange.index])

I expected a spreadsheet with nothing in it. What I got was a spreadsheet with the duplicated data.

# Find duplicated reservation IDs in file1
duplicated_ids = file1[file1.duplicated(subset=['Reservation ID'], keep=False)]

# Remove rows with duplicated reservation IDs from file1
file1 = file1[~file1.duplicated(subset=['Reservation ID'], keep=False)]


The duplicated ID's are in a different dataframe

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
